# How to user pipeline parameters to change sink dataset paths in Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I've a Azure Synapse Pipeline that has some copy activities with parquets sinking datasets. My pipeline that runs the copy activities has a string date parameter. How to I pass this date parameters to the sink dataset and use it in the path of the blob as dynamic expression?

Comment: Can you give the parameter value that you are trying to use and what is the path that you want to build using this parameter?

Comment: The parameter is a string date like '2022-12-01' and the path is another string like 'container_blob/filename_{dateparameter}' and I want to put the {dateparameter} as '2022-12-01' for several sink datasets paths. I'm trying to put this date parameter in the linked service global parameter but don't know if its the best solution

Comment: Use a parameterized dataset. This article may help: https://causewaysolutions.com/blog/creating-reusable-datasets-in-azure-data-factory-with-parameters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If these multiple sink datasets are present in different activities of different pipelines, and you want to use the date `2022-12-01` for your path, then you can use global parameter.
- Since global parameter is a constant that can be used across multiple pipelines, it would fit the requirement.
- If these multiple sink activities are present in the same pipeline, then you can use the pipeline parameter itself.
- You can use string interpolation to include the parameter value wherever required. The following is a demonstration of the same:
- I passed the parameter value to dataset (through a parameter created in dataset called `dt`).

[image]

- Using the following dynamic content, I can create a folder with name as `filename_2022-12-01`

```
filename_@{dataset().dt}
```

[image]